# postfix SRS how to do not change Return-Path for non-forwarded emails

Tags: postfix, multiple-instances, return-path

If set postsrsd as described in https://github.com/roehling/postsrsd all incoming emails have changed Return-Path. They say you can workaround it with multiple instances of postfix. Could you show howto how to set multiple instances of postfix with non-changed Return-Path for non-forwards?